# How do I make a node title translatable?

Tags: drupal

I'd like to translate each node title as a string (using  i18n). I'm trying this function in my theme template:

```
function theme_process_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = t($variables['title']);
}
```

Yet when I refresh strings, none of my node titles are on the list. Is there something I'm missing?

And to clarify the function name is using my theme name, not the word "theme".

Comment: Hmm...strange. Can you use t() function directly in template file(s) when printing title? BTW, https://www.drupal.org/project/title

Answer (score 2):

[Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) is my usual solution for this (I use Entity Translation, it works fine with Title module).

This module replaces node titles by a regular translatable text field. You can choose wich content type titles must be replaced (on the "Manage Field" forms, you'll find a "replace" link in the title row). Pretty useful.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `t()` to translate user-supplied or variable strings. See [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) on the function.

That said, there are some solutions, one is to use the built-in [language support for entity fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1500308). Following that you should be able to do something like this in a field hook (in a module, not in your template):

```
$langcode = $field_info['translatable'] ? $content_langcode : LANGUAGE_NONE;
$entity->{$field_name}[$langcode][0]['value'] = t("Salut!");
```